# Confirm box does not submit the first time

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm using C# and I have an ImageButton inside a repeater. I want this button to have a confirm box and then trigger the itemCommand of the repeater.

The problem is the first time you click on it the submit is not triggered. Works just fine for the rest of the times you click on it, but not for the first.

The code of the aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Doconfirm(message) {

        var proceed = confirm(message);
        if (proceed) {
            Page_ValidationActive = false;
        }
        return proceed;
    }
</script>

 <asp:Repeater ID="rptOrders" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptOrders_itemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptOrders_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" ID="DeleteImageButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Enabled = "false" ImageUrl="aux_images/bg-ie-select-width-13px.png"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
```

The code behind of this is:

```
 protected void rptOrders_itemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
         //Some code...
         ImageButton LnkDelete = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("DeleteImageButton");
                    LnkDelete.Enabled = true;
                    LnkDelete.OnClientClick = "return Doconfirm('" + this.GetLocalResourceObject("ConfirmText") + "');";
                    LnkDelete.ID = Detail.OrderId.ToString();
                    LnkDelete.CommandArgument = Detail.OrderId.ToString();
                    LnkDelete.CommandName = "Delete";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void rptOrders_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
        {
            //Some code...
        }
    }
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'm noticing in your code is the line (in rptOrders_itemDataBound)

```
LnkDelete.ID = Detail.OrderId.ToString();
```

which is superfluous at best.

My theory is that you have additional controls on your page in the same validation group that are not valid when pressing the delete button. But in the javascript part you're deactivating page validation and so the first click is swallowed but any further clicks will succeed.

So if you use different validation groups it should work just fine.

Comment: Added a solution to my answer :)